# Record a small text string info a textfile at the server side

Tags: javascript

I have to record some text strings from an HTML webpage into a text file to be processed by another program.

I've tried many javascript examples but so far I haven't even managed to get a file.

```
<script>

    function wFile(filepath, output) {
        var txtFile = new File([""], filepath);
        txtFile.open("w"); //
        txtFile.writeln(output);
        txtFile.close();
    }

    wFile("C:/temp/test.txt","some text");

</script>
```

> F12 results in: Uncaught TypeError: txtFile.open is not a function

Comment: You cannot save a file on the server from the client directly (you can save it locally under a sandbox if you'd like). It's unclear what you are trying to do. You probably need to call a URL that can write the files for you

Comment: I'm used to  asp.net and creating  files at the server side is just a single line. In case javascript is not handy i could look for php the achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<script>` tags are used on HTML webpages for client-side Javascript. You can't create local files from a web browser as the browser is sand boxed from both the users computer and the server that sent the files.

You are probably looking for [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/) which is a server-side platform for Javascript.